# Java button/gridbaglayout

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

Is there a way to either set a max size of a button(or non re sizable), or not allow the columns in a gridbaglayout to change size if a component grows ?

```
i.e 
    btn.setMaxsize();
    btn.resizable(false);
    gridbaglayout.lockcolumns();
```

This is not what I am coding but what I am trying to achieve. Thanks for any help provided.

Comment: Have you tried setting gridweight to 0?

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org). If you set the field `fill` of your `GridBagConstraint` to `GridBagConstraint.NONE` your button will always keep the same size (its preferred size).

Comment: You must have something wrong in your code then. Anyway, using setMin/Max/Pref size is really not recommended. This is going down a very bad road which will eventually lead to more problems and less solutions.

Comment: Check out [this question and its accepted answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7229226/should-i-avoid-the-use-of-setpreferredmaximumminimumsize-methods-in-java-swi)

Comment: Guillaume your solution works as well. I was commenting on Prasanth answer. Thank you all for the quick answers.

Comment: I am going with guillaume polet's solution. Thanks again

Answer (score -1, accepted):

set below 3 properties with max value.

```
    btnNewButton.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(10, 10));
    btnNewButton.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(10, 10));
    btnNewButton.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(10, 10));
```

Comment: width of the button and the height is set by new Dimension(width, height)

Comment: Check out [this question and its accepted answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7229226/should-i-avoid-the-use-of-setpreferredmaximumminimumsize-methods-in-java-swi). Using setMaximum/Minimum/PreferredSize is a bad idea.

Comment: See also [Should I avoid the use of set(Preferred|Maximum|Minimum)Size methods in Java Swing](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7229226/230513)?

Comment: Thanks for the additional info!